# A Project has many Sites. Both Projects and Sites can be viewed and edited. What's a good experience for this that doesn't overwhelm the user?

Tags: usability, forms

Web app where each Project contains many Sites. Projects and Sites are able to be viewed and edited. I have a feeling that clumping everything on one screen might be a bit overwhelming, especially considering that each Site's "lots of info" is scrolling a couple full browser heights.

So currently I have a table of Project rows like this with nested expandable rows to preview the Sites.

```
Project1
  - Site1
  - Site2
  - Site3
Project2
  - Site1
  - Site2
  - Site3
```

Then when you click on one of the projects, it shows that Project's description and info for all of the Sites.

```
Project1
 - info
Site1
 - lots of info
Site2
 - lots of info
Site3
 - lots of info
```

I haven't deciding the editing part yet, but my first impression was that editing here might be too much information all at once.

A Site always belongs to a Project. Should they be viewed separately or together? Should they be edited separately or together?

I tend to like using the same screen and modals, but this feels a bit different because it's so much information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the second view would look more like a book that doesn't seem to result in a good user experience. Very likely there is no need to have two separate views either. A single one can comprize the whole data if it's properly organized.

An approach used for email management can be applied to your case resulting in a non-overwhelming view with a structure as outlined below:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Project1                            | ProjectX - SiteY                         |
|  Project's info beginning           | Lots of info about the selected entry.   |
|   - Site1                           |                                          |
|      Info beginning of the Site1    |                                          |
|   - Site2                           |                                          |
|      Info beginning of the Site2    |                                          |
|   - Site3                           |                                          |
|      Info beginning of the Site3    |                                          |
| Project2                            |                                          |
|   - Site1                           |                                          |
|      Info beginning of the Site1    |                                          |
|   - Site2                           |                                          |
|      Info beginning of the Site2    |                                          |
|   - Site3                           |                                          |
|      Info beginning of the Site3    |                                          |
| ...                                 |                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 <Pagination if necessary>
```

A good example of such view might be the one available in [Gmail Labs:  Preview Pane](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2011/08/new-in-labs-preview-pane.html).

Though using such approach an entry's info can be edited with a projects & sites structure displayed next to it, it's not preferred in all situations and some users might want to edit an entry in a separate view, fully dedicated only for editing. Thus, a handy feature to open an edit pane in a separate view would be a good addition.